# Issue getting the total sale accounted by each store in MDX (in percent)

Tags: ssas, mdx

I want to be able to create the following table in SSRS:

```
StoreKey    StorePercentage
1024        50 %
1037        20 %
1111        13 %
1949        27 %
```

where I've encountered that it was not possible to create a chart using Aggregated data. Hence I try to specify the `StorePercentage` value in SSAS (as I am using an analysis server as a data source in `SSRS`) and import that into `SSRS` and use the value *off the bat*. With the purpose of creating this data set I've started to test this query in `SSMS`:

```
With MEMBER [Measures].[StorePercentage] AS
    SUM (
            {
            [Dim Store2].[Store Key],[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-23]:[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-29]
            }, [Measures].[Total Price] 
        )
    / SUM
        ( 
            {
                [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-23]:[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-29]
            }, [Measures].[Total Sales]
        )
    Select non empty
        {
        [Measures].[Total Price],[Measures].[StorePercentage] 
        } on 0,
    [Dim Store2].[Store Key].children on 1
    FROM [theyseemecubintheyhatin]
```

But this gives me:

```
StoreKey    Total Price     StorePercentage
1024        50424           #Error
1037        3434            #Error
1111        1333            #Error
1949        2443            #Error
```

, i.e. my calculated measure seem to be problematic.

What I essentially try to do in the query, in the `With MEMBER` clause is:

> SUM(Total sale made by each store and date range separately)/SUM(Total Sales for all stores over the time interval)

but I seem to be having some issues with this. I've tried a bunch of different combinations of `{`,`(` in the query but I haven't gotten it to work.

Does anyone have a clue? When I tried to Google this issue, the queries I found were related to getting data for a measure and a specific date range, but I need to query for each store as well.

Comment: did you double click on `#Error` in the results pain - in ssms it will tell you the error when  you double-click

Comment: @whytheq       I had no idea about that! Very helpful information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will make more sense:

```
With 
Member [Measures].[StorePercentage] AS
[Measures].[Total Price]
/
([Dim Store2].[Store Key].[All],[Measures].[Total Price])

select 
non empty {[Measures].[Total Price],[Measures].[StorePercentage]} on 0,
non empty [Dim Store2].[Store Key].[Store Key].Members on 1
from [theyseemecubintheyhatin]
where ({[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-23]:[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-29]})
```

The problem code is here:

```
{[Dim Store2].[Store Key],[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-23]:[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-29]}
```

Because **[Dim Store2].[Store Key]** doesn't mean anything.